# Как поменять два массива местами?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, замена

Пусть дан массив из n элементов и массив из m элементов. 
Нужно придумать алгоритм, по которому элементы второго массива заполнят первый массив, а элементы первого массива - второй. То есть нужно поменять местами два отрезка.

Пример:

{1,2,3} {4,5,6,7,8} --> {4,5,6} {7,8,1,2,3}

Пользоваться новой вспомогательной переменной или массивом нельзя. Имеются только параметры n, m и элементы массивов.

**Обновление**

Мне удалось придумать, как менять местами два элемента без помощи новой переменной, но для меня остается загадкой то, как поменять их в угодном мне порядке, чтобы получились нужные массивы.

Comment: @jeyando, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Мне удалось придумать, как менять местами два элемента без помощи новой переменной, но для меня остается загадкой то, как поменять их в угодном мне порядке, чтобы получились нужные массивы.

Comment: У тебя есть длинна массивов. меняешь числа 1-4-7, 2-5-8 по кругу, пока не перенесутся элементы от(m-n)до m на первые места. после можно расставить на нужные позиции.

Comment: Точнее, сначала обмен между массивами (по размеру меньшего), затем циклический сдвиг влево большего массива на размер меньшего (тоже можно выполнять обменом соседних элементов в 2-х вложенных циклах).

--

@jeyando, для обмена 2-х элементов без промежуточной переменной Вы, я думаю, использовали операцию "XOR"?

Answer (score 1):

Объясню, как сделать это для 2-х переменных, потом попробую для массива.

Есть a = 2 и b = 3, тогда можно сделать b = b + a, тогда a = 2, а b = 5 и провести следующие 2 операции: a = b - a; (тогда a = 3, b = 5) b = b - a, тогда a = 3, b = 2. Готово!

Для массива a из 3 элементов и b из 5 элементов делаешь то же самое (a[1] с b[1], потом a[2] с b[2]...) и так до 3, а последние 2 просто вставляешь в другой массив, удаляя из начального.

P.S. Могу рассказать более подробно, если не понятно. Только напишите сначала язык программирования, на котором это требуется сделать.

Comment: Обычно такой обмен для целых записывают так:

    #define SWAPX(a,b) (a ^= b, b ^= a, a ^= b)

Comment: Я не знал язык, на котором нужна задача, поэтому не стал писать ничего "языкозависимого". Алгоритм довольно короткий на C получился, это радует. Хотя для новичка битовые операции могут показаться не очень то и понятными, но зато работают быстро!